# Do Klingon place names have literal meanings in Klingonese?

Tags: star-trek, klingon-language

On Earth, proper names are often derived from words, often from an archaic language, to describe the place or object, or sometimes to express some ideal which the namers wish to associate with the subject that they are naming: for instance, Philadelphia is composed of Greek roots meant to convey brotherly love.

In Star Trek, has there been a place name (Qo'nos, Praxis, Khitomer, Boreth, etc) which is formed from Klingonese roots?

Comment: I'm fairly certain "Praxis" is formed from the Klingon root for "Awesome".

Comment: Actually most places are just descriptors of the place. Very few are named for some ideal. I won't comment on the Klingon place names, cuz I don't know, but my guess is no, they don't.

Comment: What Durakken said: among placenames, *Philadelphia* (and *Pennsylvania*, for that matter) is very much the exception, not the rule. Your premise -- that most placenames were originally formed from meaningful words -- is sound, but your chosen example is not.

Comment: re: [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32695280#32695280) - Hello. Hail and well met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed in the semi-canon reference [Klingon for the Galactic Traveler](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Klingon_for_the_Galactic_Traveler) written by Mark Okrand.

> **The origins of most Klingon place names are not known, having been
>   lost to history.** Sometimes, however, the meaning of a place name is
>   clear, such as the Sakrej region's {HuD beQ yoS} ("Flat Mountain
>   district") and, of course, {veng wa'DIch} ("First City"). On rare
>   occasion, a place's name can be traced to an individual or family,
>   such as {Qotmagh Sep} ("Krotmag region"), derived from {Qotmagh}, the
>   leader of a powerful house who, centuries ago, conquered neighboring
>   areas, or {ruq'e'vet} ("Ruk'- evet"), a city in the {ghevchoq Sep}
>   ("Gevchok region"), named for a warrior (whether actual or
>   mythological is a matter of dispute) who singlehandedly defeated an
>   invading force.

So no, none of the major locations mentioned in the canon Star Trek universe have their root in the actual *modern* Klingonese language.